# With the help of JIT, the longer program runs, the faster it is?

Tags: java, jit

I've tried to run java program in pure interpreted mode and the speed of that program is intolerable.

As time elapses, JIT should be able to compile more byte-code to native code, therefore program should run faster. Am I right? If my application(such as Tomcat) runs for several weeks, months, is it possible that JIT has compiled most of the byte-code into native code?

I appreciate your answers, thanks!

Comment: And then there is deterioration due to resource leaks, memory leaks, threading problems. Though "intolerable" reeks of database: either SQL (indices, queries) or Java lists/nested loops/multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the help of JIT, the longer program runs, the faster it is?

Up to a point yes.  Once everything that matters has been JIT compiled, it will stop getting faster.

> If my application(such as Tomcat) runs for several weeks, months, is it possible that JIT has compiled most of the byte-code into native code?

It is possible that all the code will have been JIT compiled.  It is also possible that some code won't have been JIT compiled.

The granularity of JIT compilation is a method.  But the JIT compiler only decides to JIT compile a method after the interpreter notices that it has spent more than a certain amount of time running it.  If you have a method that is never called, it won't be JIT compiled.

Not that it matters.  If a method is never or hardly ever used, then the fact that it is (still) interpreted probably has minimal influence on performance.

---

As Joop Eggen points out there are other issues that can cause a long running program to slow down ... or speed up.  For example:

- Slowdowns can be caused by resource leaks of various kinds.
- Speedups can be due to stabilization of heap storage management ("warmup") and population of caches.